# jQuery Validate Plugin turn off text label globally?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I'm currently using this bit of code to loop through all inputs with a certain class and set the message to an empty string, but was wondering if there's a more elegant way to turn off all "next-to-the-input" error messages. Been through a few tries using combinations of wrapper and container and grouping messages, but the defaults are always there and show messages when those things try to hide them. Main culprit is inline style of "display: inline" IIRC.

```
$("input.baseAllocationAmount").each(function(idx, elm){
    validationMessages[$(elm).attr("name")] = "";
});

var formValidationOptions = {
    wrapper: "span",
    messages: validationMessages
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried playing around with some of the [plugin's options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)?
looks like you could use `showErrors`, or possibly `errorClass` or

```
errorElement
```